# What probability distribution formula to use?

Tags: statistics

I need help in solving the following problems.

1. Homeland Security and missile defense technology make it paramount that we be able to detect incoming projectiles or missiles. To make the defense successful, multiple radar screens are required. Suppose it is determined that three independent screens are to be operated and the probability that any one screen will detect an incoming missile is 0.8. Obviously, if no screens detect an incoming projectile, the system is unworthy and must be improved.
   a. What is the probability that an incoming missile will not be detected by any of the 3 screens?
   b. What is the probability that the missile will be detected by only 1 screen?
   c. What is the probability that it will be detected by at least 2 out of 3 screens?
2. Consider problem no. 1. Suppose it is important that the overall system be as near as perfect as possible. Assuming the quality of the screens are as indicated in problem no. 1;
   a. How many are needed to insure that the probability that the missile gets through undetected is 0.0001?
   b. Suppose it is decided to stay with only 3 screens and attempt to improve the screen detection ability. What must be the individual screen effectiveness (i.e., probability of detection), in order to achieve the effectiveness required from (a)?

Comment: What type of distributions have you learned in class so far? Do you have any idea about which one might apply here?

Comment: what is the relation of this question with the choice of a probability distribution?

Comment: Would you mind reformulating the problem in less military or at least less US-centric terminology?

Comment: @joriki You mean, like, doing something else than copying verbatim the text of the homework here? Strange idea... If one starts along this path, one might end having some ideas of one's own about the way to solve the problem and presenting them (as well as the things one tried and which failed) together with the question. What a scary perspective.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Hint**: The first part is a simple probability question. The second and third part requires Binomial PDF/CDF.

*Solutions*:

a)

> a) We have $\Pr(\text{no missile detected}) = 1 - 0.8 = 0.2$. The probability of this happening three times is $0.2^3$, or $0.008$.

b)

> b) Binomial PDF is used here. We have three trials, each with a probability of success of $0.8$. From here, you can calculate that the probability that only one screen catches the missile is $0.096$.

c)

> c) Binomial CDF is our distribution here. We have three trials, and we want to find the probability of: $\Pr(\text{three screens detect}) + \Pr(\text{two screens detect}) = 1 - (\Pr(\text{one screen detects}) + \Pr(\text{no screen detects}))$. The probability of success is $0.8$. We now apply the binomial CDF and find the probability of $(\Pr(\text{one screen detects}) + \Pr(\text{no screen detects}) = 0.104$. The resulting probability is $1 - 0.104 = 0.896$.

c) Alternative

> c) Alternatively, calculate using Binomial PDF. We have $\Pr(\text{two screen detects}) = 0.384$. $\Pr(\text{three screen detects}) = 0.512$. Add the two to get $0.896$.

1. **Hint**: For the first part, apply the same reasoning as part a) of question one, except now you are solving for the number of screens. You will need logarithms. For the second part, apply the same reasoning as part a) of question one. You will need roots, specifically $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$.

a)

> a) We have $0.2^x = 0.0001$. Taking the $log_{0.2}$ of both sides, we get that we need $5.77 \to 6$ screens.

b)

> b) We have $p^3 = 0.0001$. Taking the cube root of both sides, we get $p \approx 0.04642$. But this is *not* the detection probability the missiles should have. This is the probability of *not* detecting the missile in order to have a probability of $0.0001$. Doing $1 - p$, we get the missiles need success with probability $\approx 0.9536$.

Comment: Hi George! We are now learning Binomial, Hypergeometric and Poisson. After I posted my question, I tried answering question no. 1 and I got the same answers as you did for a and b, but not for c.

Comment: @Violet, I just redid the question in two ways and I seem to be getting the same answer ($0.896$). What answer do you get?

Comment: @George... I used excel (toink on me!) and I got 0.384 for letter c.

Comment: That's the probability that exactly two out of the three screens work. We want the probability that two _or_ three screens work. Adding $0.8^3$, the probability that all three screens work, you get the desired solution. Make sure when using the Binomial Distribution, you choose correctly between CDF and PDF. CDF is for _at least_, PDF is for _exactly_. So the desired probability is $1 - \text{BinomialCDF}(n=3, p=(1 - 4/5), k=1)$ (the probability that 1 or less radar systems do not fail = the probability that 2 or more radar systems work).

Comment: @Violet, does this explanation make sense to you?

Comment: Yes it does... the thing is we were not informed of what Binomial CDF and Binomial PDF are. That's why I got confused. We were just taught to compute of Binomial Distribution. What formula did you use for 1b?

Comment: @Violet, If you are learning "Binomial", it probably is Binomial PDF. Binomial CDF is sort of like a sum of Binomial PDF. For example, $\text{CDF}(n=3, p=1/5, k=2) = \text{PDF}(n=3, p=1/5, k=1) + \text{PDF}(n=3, p=1/5, k=0)$. I'll update my answer to use the ordinary Binomial PDF instead (although you will probably learn CDF as well).

Comment: Thank you so much! Trying to solve number 7 now...